# Add data to list inside list using loop Python

Tags: python, list

I am making a student database and I want to enter 5 marks for 5 different subjects. I have created two lists:

1. The list which will hold 5 different marks for 5 different subjects
2. The list which will hold 5 marks as one item for one student.

I want the output to display one list inside which a number of lists are displayed and each sublist should have only 5 marks for each student. However, the output I get is a list containing all the marks.
Desired Output:
If I enter [1,2,3,4,5] as marks of first student and [6,7,8,9,10] as marks of second student, then the list should print [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

Here is my code:

```
def ad():
    five_marks_of_one_student = []
    marks_of_different_students = []
    choice = "y"

    while choice == "y":
        i = 1
        while i <= 5:
            one_mark = int(input("Enter marks of " + str(i) + " subject:"))
            five_marks_of_one_student.append(one_mark)
            i = i + 1
        marks_of_different_students.append(five_marks_of_one_student)
        choice = input("Enter choice y for repeat:")

    print(marks_of_different_students)


ad()
```

Comment: First, correct your code indention.

Comment: Can you please provide your desire output as an example

Comment: You need to `five_marks_of_one_student=[]` after the `marks_of_different_students.append(five_marks_of_one_student)`

Comment: Move `five_marks_of_one_student = []` inside the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Thankyou so much, that worked. What I was doing was that I used the del list[:] command to delete the list elements once they were stored in the main list. It works now. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:
you can store name of student with result

```
def ad():
    marks_of_different_students={}
    choice="y"

    while(choice=="y"):
        name_of_student = input("Enter your name : ")
        i=1
        five_marks_of_one_student=[]
        while(i<=5):
            one_mark=int(input("Enter marks of "+str(i)+" subject : "))
            five_marks_of_one_student.append(one_mark)
            i=i+1
        marks_of_different_students[name_of_student]=five_marks_of_one_student
        choice=input("Enter choice y for repeat : ")
    print(marks_of_different_students)

ad()
```

Output:

```
Enter your name : abc
Enter marks of 1 subject : 98
Enter marks of 2 subject : 15
Enter marks of 3 subject : 45
Enter marks of 4 subject : 2
Enter marks of 5 subject : 2
Enter choice y for repeat : y
Enter your name : xyz
Enter marks of 1 subject : 55
Enter marks of 2 subject : 59
Enter marks of 3 subject : 68
Enter marks of 4 subject : 47
Enter marks of 5 subject : 59
Enter choice y for repeat : 
{'abc': [98, 15, 45, 2, 2], 'xyz': [55, 59, 68, 47, 59]}
```

Comment: you can handle exception of input for entry also.

Comment: Have you used tuple here instead of list?